# Docker Container Running But it throws the error Template does not Exist

Tags: python, django, docker

Hi I'm New In Docker I Have Created A Django Application Its Running in Local machine Good But
When I try To run In docker Container its Run Properly But When I sent Request The Found The Error Template Does Not Exist

```
 Dockerfile
#syntax=docker/dockerfile:1
#FROM ubuntu:latest
FROM ubuntu:latest
FROM python:3.8-slim-buster
WORKDIR /app
#COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt

#RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
#
#CMD python . /manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"""
# pull the official base image

# set work directory


# set environment variables
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

# install dependencies
RUN apt-get update&& \
    apt-get -y install sudo
RUN apt-get install -y tesseract-ocr
RUN apt-get install -y build-essential libpoppler-cpp-dev pkg-config python-dev mupdf

RUN apt-get install ffmpeg libsm6 libxext6  -y

RUN apt-get install -y default-jre
RUN apt-get install -y default-jdk


RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y python3-pip
RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip
#RUN pip3 install virtualenv
#RUN python3 -m virtualenv env
#RUN source env/bin/activate
COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt

RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
# copy project
COPY . /app

EXPOSE 8000

CMD ["python3", "manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000"]
#
```

My Docker File Look Like that

```
docker-cpmpose.yml
version: "3"
   
services:
   web:
       build: .
       command: python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
       ports:
           - 8000:8000

Folder Structure

    Directory: E:\djangoproject\blogproject


Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
d-----        22-12-2022     19:39                Blog
d-----        22-12-2022     19:39                Blogproject
d-----        22-12-2022     19:40                venv
-a----        22-12-2022     19:46         192512 db.sqlite3
-a----        21-12-2022     18:02            153 docker-compose.yml
-a----        22-12-2022     15:51           1097 Dockerfile
-a----        24-12-2021     13:00            689 manage.py
-a----        20-12-2022     13:09            578 requirements.txt
```

My Template folder Is in Blog app templates/blog/templtes.html

when i run #docker-compose up then my image server is start but then i sent request from my brouser the i get the error page

```
TemplateDoesNotExist at /
blog/pages.html 
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/
Django Version: 3.2.8
Exception Type: TemplateDoesNotExist
Exception Value:    
blog/pages.html 
Exception Location: /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py, line 84, in reraise
Python Executable:  /usr/local/bin/python3
Python Version: 3.8.16
Python Path:    
['/app',
 '/usr/local/lib/python38.zip',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.8',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages']
Server time:    Fri, 23 Dec 2022 05:53:42 +0000
Template-loader postmortem
Django tried loading these templates, in this order:

Using engine django:

This engine did not provide a list of tried templates.
Error during template rendering
In template /app/Blog/templates/blog/base.html, error at line 0
```

some one can help me to fix this error

Answer (score 0):

According to your Dockerfile, you must copy your django project from one folder to another and you didn't set workdir.

Instead of this:

```
COPY . /app  #here only you copied but didn't set where to copy
```

Try this way:

```
COPY ./app /app    #here copied Django project from one folder to another.
WORKDIR /app
```

Note: Don't forget to re-build this Dockerfile.

Comment: now hving new problem python3: can't open file 'manage.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Comment: first check where manage.py file is present. It must be in project root

Comment: please tell the command to check bcoz i still having issue i chaned this COPY . /app/app
WORKDIR /app and one workdir is on top

Comment: remove workdir from top and then re-build and try